# Replacing CoreData with profession data base for performance

Tags: mysql, performance, sqlite, core-data

We have a large Mac Application that uses CoreData to store about 10+ GB worth of data, to improve performance we break it up into smaller CoreData stores of about 0.25 GB to 1 GB representing the different projects a user use simultaneously, this lets users turn on and off which projects they want to work with and improves performance especially when they do things that span all active projects, we also have all our fetching and writing to CoreData in background threads so as not to block the user. The source of the data is from a remote shared MySQL database, uses don't alter the data in any way its just inspected, copying the data locally lets users use the data in ways that would be too slow on the remote database and when they are working off line.
CoreData is using SQLite, I was recently reading people comment on how SQLite does not compare to products like PostSQL, MySQL and Oracle, would we benefit in performance if we used something like PostSQL or MySQL instead of CoreData, or do the benefits only come into play for multiple of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many sites comparing the underlying database systems. [Here's one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems). From your description above, since this is not a multiuser write-heavy application, there is little to be gained by moving away from SQLite. You might consider moving to using your server database, but you've probably ruled that out and it is unlikely to make things much faster.

Moving away from Core Data will incur you development costs and provide an unlikely performance speedup. From your description above, your team has already done an excellent job partitioning the database for excellent parallel access. Hence, I would ask your team to show you where the system is slow? And then ask them how they would change it to perform better? And then ask them how much it will cost the team to deliver that performance? Then you'll know whether to reengineer your solution. Based upon your above description, your system is fine.